# How to rewrite row_number() windowing sql function to python polars?

Tags: python

I'd like to rewrite the following sql code to python polars:

```
row_number() over (partition by a,b order by c*d desc nulls last) as rn
```

Suppose we have a dataframe like:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"],
        "b": ["Z", "Z", "T", "Z", "T"],
        "c": [1, 2, 1, 3, 3],
        "d": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    }
)
```

I was trying something like this, but it does not work:

```
df.select(
    [
     df.with_row_count(name='rn').sort(pl.col("c")*pl.col("d"), descending=True, nulls_last=True).over(["a","b"]).alias("rn")
    ]
)
```

Any ideas?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that it can be solved in one command:

```
df.with_columns(rn = (pl.col("c") * pl.col("d")) \
                      .fill_null(-1) \
                      .rank("ordinal",descending=True)\
                      .over(["a","b"]) \
                )
```